# Use Windows Authentication AND Standard User Accounts in ASP Identity/Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I am currently working on an external identity library that can be easily connected to any new Blazor server app. This already works, but currently only the normal user account authentication is implemented.

I would like to include Windows authentication + username+password accounts authentication:

If: The login with the Windows user fails or the user is not found in the AspNetUsers table, then you should be able to login with a normal (username+password) user account.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be implemented?

thank you in advance for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

So our team had a similar issue. In short, you need something like Identity Server, which is renamed to Duende Software (no longer free): https://duendesoftware.com/products/identityserver

Alternatively, using something like Azure Active Directory. We're considering this and I believe this would allow synchronizing with your Active Directory plus add independent users.